# How is iAd work with apple

Tags: xcode

I have an app which already on Apple Store, i want to ask about the iAd and how to calculate the interest in a simple way.

Let's  say the app has been downloaded 10000 times, how will the iAd will work. I mean how much money I will have from that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iAd Revenue is not based on downloads. It's based on a complicated mixture of user exposure to ads and their interactions with them. It is impossible to know anything exact for ad revenue for an app until it is out in the wild, as user behavior can be difficult to predict.

You could possibly extrapolate from other apps' data, but I don't have any data to share with you myself.